# Making a folder lock application using java

Tags: java

I've got a project from my college to make a folder lock application using Java.
I have no idea how to go about it. Please give some clues on how to make a folder\file password protected ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally native dependent.

You need to protect/encrypt/hide the folder using native features.

and if your app validates the user reverse the process

Answer (score 2):

A daemon thread or service will be running,for lock folder management that is for locking,unlocking, displaying alerts etc..

Going with fast and efficient encryption and decryption algorithm is also another challenge as the number of files in the folders grow ,the efficiency should not decline.

At the same time,users and password list should be secured which should not be os dependents. File tampering etc should also be dealt with !!

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want it dependent on a specific OS you can go this way:

- zip it using:

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html

- encrypt it using:

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html

- delete safely the original data by first replacing all the characters in the files with random data and then deleting those files.